# JMeter 5.0 distributed testing connection exception error

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I'm using JMeter 5, and trying to setup a distributed testing environment. I have one client and one server for now. The Client Jmeter.properties file has the *remote_host* set to server ip. *`server.rmi.ssl.disable=true`* in both client and server JMeter.properties.

- Client & server are on the same subnet and have same versions of Java and JMeter
- Server starts up without issues, using jmeter-server.bat
- In client when JMeter is started in GUI mode and clicked on Run>Remote Start>server ip, getting an error, after about 30 secs, as
  shown below.

**`Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: #.#.#.#; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`**

Did anyone get the same/similar issue and how did you resolve it? Please, give me all details since this is the first time Im setting this up.

Note: I've many answers for older versions of JMeter that do not seem to work.

Logs:

> 2019-01-04 12:52:36,319 INFO o.j.r.JARSourceHTTP: Found cached repo    2019-01-04 12:52:36,463 INFO o.j.r.PluginManager: Plugins Status:    [jpgc-graphs-basic=2.0, jpgc-plugins-manager=1.3, jmeter-core=5.0,    jmeter-ftp=5.0, jmeter-http=5.0, jmeter-jdbc=5.0, jmeter-jms=5.0,    jmeter-junit=5.0, jmeter-java=5.0, jmeter-ldap=5.0, jmeter-mail=5.0,    jmeter-mongodb=5.0, jmeter-native=5.0, jmeter-tcp=5.0,    jmeter-components=5.0] 2019-01-04 12:52:37,879 INFO    o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is    org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser    2019-01-04 12:52:37,880 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for    application/xhtml+xml is    org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser    2019-01-04 12:52:37,880 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for    application/xml is    org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser    2019-01-04 12:52:37,880 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for    text/xml is    org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser    2019-01-04 12:52:37,880 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for    text/vnd.wap.wml is    org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser 2019-01-04    12:52:37,880 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is    org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser 2019-01-04    12:52:38,020 INFO o.a.j.e.KeyToolUtils: Exception checking for    keytool existence, will return false, try another way. 2019-01-04    12:52:38,185 INFO o.a.j.e.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'C:\Program    Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin\keytool' 2019-01-04 12:52:38,186 INFO    o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will    use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file C:\Program    Files\apache-jmeter-5.0\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin\proxyserver.jks    2019-01-04 12:52:38,343 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Default    base='C:\Windows\System32' 2019-01-04 12:52:38,734 INFO    o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times    2019-01-04 12:52:38,734 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult:    sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1 2019-01-04    12:52:38,734 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true    2019-01-04 12:52:38,734 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult:    sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000 2019-01-04 12:52:41,112 INFO    o.a.j.g.a.Load: Loading file: D:\APEX Performance    Tests\BetsAPI-MgmtPerformanceTests.jmx 2019-01-04 12:52:41,112 INFO    o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='D:\APEX Performance Tests'    2019-01-04 12:52:41,228 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX)    version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2 2019-01-04 12:52:41,233 INFO    o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8    2019-01-04 12:52:41,234 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService    properties version 5.0 2019-01-04 12:52:41,237 INFO    o.a.j.s.SaveService: Loading file: D:\APEX Performance    Tests\BetsAPI-MgmtPerformanceTests.jmx 2019-01-04 12:52:41,714 INFO    o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='D:\APEX Performance Tests'    2019-01-04 12:52:52,046 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Configuring    remote engine: HQ-DEV-CORE-04:1099 2019-01-04 12:52:52,048 INFO    o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is    set to 'true' 2019-01-04 12:53:13,118 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner:    Starting remote engines 2019-01-04 12:53:13,118 INFO    o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Starting the test @ Fri Jan 04 12:53:13    PST 2019 (1546635193118) 2019-01-04 12:53:13,118 INFO    o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method    2019-01-04 12:53:13,120 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI    as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true' 2019-01-04 12:53:13,120    INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as    server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true' 2019-01-04 12:53:13,122 INFO    o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 2019-01-04    12:53:13,125 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as    server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true' 2019-01-04 12:53:13,125 INFO    o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is    set to 'true' 2019-01-04 12:53:13,142 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils:    Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'    2019-01-04 12:53:13,142 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI    as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true' 2019-01-04 12:53:13,143    INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for    this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 2019-01-04 12:53:13,143    INFO o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using    DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 2019-01-04 12:53:13,143 INFO    o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is    set to 'true' 2019-01-04 12:53:13,143 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils:    Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'    2019-01-04 12:53:13,144 INFO o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using    batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100,    time=60000 2019-01-04 12:53:13,144 INFO    o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender    for this run 2019-01-04 12:53:13,144 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling    SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true' 2019-01-04    12:53:13,144 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as    server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true' 2019-01-04 12:53:13,144 INFO    o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this    run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 2019-01-04 12:53:13,144 INFO    o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender    for this run 2019-01-04 12:53:13,144 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling    SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true' 2019-01-04    12:53:13,144 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as    server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true' 2019-01-04 12:53:13,144 INFO    o.a.j.s.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this    run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 2019-01-04 12:53:13,145 INFO    o.a.j.s.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender    for this run 2019-01-04 12:53:34,151 ERROR    o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Error in rconfigure() method    java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host:
>          169.254.61.109; nested exception is:     java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect 2019-01-04 12:53:34,152 INFO    o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Interrupting RMI Reaper 2019-01-04    12:53:42,043 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been    started

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to connect all the computer in the same network? It's mean you can using Ip from another computer.
And you have start jmeter-server.bat in all computer you using distribute

Comment: I did start jmeter-server.bat in all server computer and all both machines are in the same subnetwork.

Comment: Please check java version, try with one client first.

Comment: Thanks. Currently, only using two machines, one client and one server. Java version and Jmeter version are exactly the same and the latest.

Answer (score 0):

> Connection refused to host: 169.254.61.109

**169.254.61.109** resides in [link-local address space](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927), normally machines get IP address from this range by [auto-configuration i.e. when DHCP server cannot be found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735).

So double check your network configuration by executing [`ipconfig /all`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipconfig) command or via [Control Panel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13764/windows-where-is-control-panel)

You can force JMeter to bind to specific IP address by setting [`java.rmi.server.hostname`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html) property or `RMI_HOST_DEF` [environment variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) like:

```
jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=your_IP_address
```

make sure that the IP address is not in link-local network

More information:

- [Remote Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks, and I'll try these suggestions

Comment: Thanks and the issue has been resolved. It was related to what you have specified and fixed by out admins.